# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "oficial" y "oficioso"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

Hace unos días leía la noticia [Podemos Galicia no logra una lista única para las primarias de En Marea](http://www.eldiario.es/politica/Podemos-Galicia-lista-primarias-Marea_0_548745576.html). En ella se habla de la composición de listas para unas eleccions primarias en Podemos, un partido político español. Bueno, esto no tiene relevancia.

La cuestión es que la noticia tiene la siguiente entradilla:

> El partido presenta dos candidaturas **oficiales** y una ***oficiosa*** al proceso que dirimirá la lista de la confluencia a las autonómicas del 25 de septiembre

Ya en el cuerpo de la noticia se lee:

> La tercera candidatura no cuenta con el sello de Podemos aunque algunos de sus promotores y valedores sí son importantes referencias del partido (...)

Lo que da a pensar que oficial es lo que emana del partido en sí mismo, mientras que oficioso es algo que puede salir del partido, pero [*off the record*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_the_record).

El DRAE indica que [*oficioso*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qvz40Hi) es:

> 6. adj. Por contraposición a oficial, que hace o dice alguien sin formal ejercicio del cargo público que tiene.

Pero claramente no parece el significado que se usa en la noticia.

Investigando un poco más veo el debate ['oficial' u 'oficioso'](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=42777) en el foro del Centro Virtual Cervantes:

> Quizá por uso podría entenderse por oficioso aquello que se da a conocer antes que sea oficial, por lo que todavía no ha entrado en vigor y que con casi toda probabilidad será oficial. Luego ya, de ahí a que se aprovechen y con la expresión oficioso expresen lo que uno quiere que sea es otra cuestión.

Por lo que concluyo con la pregunta: ¿qué diferencia hay exactamente entre oficial y oficioso? ¿Es la que indico arriba, en cuanto a que algo tiene el "sello" del organismo o no?

Comment: En mi opinión, el uso de *oficiosa* en la noticia es incorrecto. Tal vez el autor se ha dejado llevar por la pareja oficial-oficioso. Aquí, yo habría preferido usar *alternativa*.

Comment: Vale, leo la noticia y no dice exactamente eso. Paso a redactar una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de leer la noticia y creo que es ligeramente diferente de lo que planteas. No son primarias en Podemos, sino en En Marea, una candidatura de la que Podemos forma parte.

La noticia habla de que Podemos, como partido, presenta dos candidaturas distintas a las primarias de En Marea; pero hay una tercera candidatura  integrada y avalada por algunos dirigentes de Podemos. No es *oficialmente* una candidatura de Podemos, pues no la ha presentado este partido, pero sí lo es *oficiosamente*, pues algunos dirigentes destacados de Podemos están ligados a la misma.

Comment: Tienes razón, pasé por alto que es un paso en el proceso de confluencia con En Marea. De todos modos, la noticia en sí es lo de menos, mi duda es sobre el uso de _oficial_ y _oficioso_, por lo que la parte de la respuesta que resulta útil es aquella donde mencionas que la candidatura (dos, de hecho) _oficial_ es la que está impulsada por Podemos como organización, mientras que la _oficiosa_ no tiene al partido detrás pero sí apoyos de gente importante en el partido. Eso resolvería la duda.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes razón, lo oficial es algo que está ya aprobado, es formal y dada de paso por alguna clase de organismo.
Lo oficioso, no es formal o no tiene ese "sello" que así lo haga valer, lo cual no implica que pueda a llegar a ser oficial si bien no es necesario tampoco.

Y ahora centrándome en el inicio de tu duda, vengo a entender que las dos listas han sido declaradas oficiales porque llevan el beneplácito del partido y por la tanto su respaldo.
La oficiosa puede ser una que, si bien no tiene la aprobacion total (sello) del partido en cuestion, sí podría convertirse en oficial si gana el proceso por el cual se dirimirá el proceso.